# Stopping a thread in Java after clicking on a JPanel generates a lot of errors

Tags: java, multithreading, swing, runtime-error

I am currently writing a program which is supposed to show an array of panels. Each panel should represent a different thread by randomly changing its own background. The frequency of changes is given at the beggining of a program along with a probability of changing panel's background to a randomly selected color or to an average of colors of its neighbours. The program works as it should but now I have to add another feature, which is stopping the thread after clicking on the panel. Such panel should stop changing its color and not take part in calculating the average color for its neighbours. The thread can be turned on again when you click again.

I have added the mouse listener to my panel class with a `mouseClicked` method, which checks if the thread is active and then it calls the `wait()` method. Otherwise is calls the `notify()` method.

Unfortunatelly, after clicking on a panel I get a lot of errors and nothing happens and I really don't know what to do next.
Any help will be good. 
I'm pasting my codes below.

**Main class:**

```java
import java.awt.GridLayout;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JPanel;

public class Simulation extends JFrame {

  JPanel mainPanel = new JPanel();

  public Simulation(int m, int n, int k, float p) {
    super("Simulation");
    setSize(n * 100, m * 100);
    setDefaultCloseOperation(EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    setLocationRelativeTo(null);
    mainPanel.setLayout(new GridLayout(m, n));

    ThreadPanel[] tp = new ThreadPanel[m * n];
    for (int i = 0; i < m * n; ++i) {
      tp[i] = new ThreadPanel(m, n, k, p, i, mainPanel);
      mainPanel.add(tp[i]);

      Thread colorChange = new Thread(tp[i]);
      colorChange.start();
    }

    add(mainPanel);
    setVisible(true);
  }

  public static void main(String[] args) {
    try {
      int m = Integer.parseInt(args[0]);
      int n = Integer.parseInt(args[1]);
      int k = Integer.parseInt(args[2]);
      float p = Float.parseFloat(args[3]);

      if (m <= 0 || n <= 0 || k <= 0 || p < 0 || p > 1) {
        throw new NumberFormatException();
      }

      new Simulation(m, n, k, p);
    } catch (NumberFormatException e) {
      System.out.println("The input data cannot be converted to the correct numbers.");
    } catch (ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException e) {
      System.out.println("Not all the necessary input data was given.");
    }
  }
}
```

**Panel class:**

```java
import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.event.MouseAdapter;
import java.awt.event.MouseEvent;
import java.util.Random;
import javax.swing.JPanel;

public class ThreadPanel extends JPanel implements Runnable {
  int m, n, k, i;
  float p, r, g ,b;
  Random rand;
  Color c;
  boolean isActive = true;
  JPanel context;

  public ThreadPanel(int m, int n, int k, float p, int i, JPanel panel) {
    this.m = m;
    this.n = n;
    this.k = k;
    this.p = p;
    this.i = i;
    context = panel;

    rand = new Random();
    changeBackground();

    addMouseListener(new MouseAdapter() {
      @Override
      public void mouseClicked(MouseEvent e) {
        try {
          if (isActive) {
            wait();
            isActive = false;
          } else {
            notify();
            isActive = true;
          }
        } catch (InterruptedException exception) {
          System.out.println("Interrupted!");
        }
      }
    });
  }

  @Override
  public void run() {
    while (true) {
      try {
        Thread.sleep((long) ((rand.nextFloat() + 0.5) * k));
        if (rand.nextFloat() <= p) {
          changeBackground();
        } else {
          changeBackgroundFromNeighbours();
        }
      } catch (InterruptedException e) {
        System.out.println("Interrupted!");
      }
    }
  }

  synchronized private void changeBackground() {
    r = rand.nextFloat();
    g = rand.nextFloat();
    b = rand.nextFloat();
    c = new Color(r, g, b);

    setBackground(c);
  }

  synchronized private void changeBackgroundFromNeighbours() {
    int north = Math.floorMod(i-n, m*n);
    int south = (i+n)%(n*m);
    int east = (i+1)%n + (i/n)*n;
    int west = Math.floorMod(i-1, n) + n*(i/n);

    Color c1 = context.getComponent(north).getBackground();
    Color c2 = context.getComponent(south).getBackground();
    Color c3 = context.getComponent(east).getBackground();
    Color c4 = context.getComponent(west).getBackground();

    int red1 = c1.getRed();
    int red2 = c2.getRed();
    int red3 = c3.getRed();
    int red4 = c4.getRed();

    int green1 = c1.getGreen();
    int green2 = c2.getGreen();
    int green3 = c3.getGreen();
    int green4 = c4.getGreen();

    int blue1 = c1.getBlue();
    int blue2 = c2.getBlue();
    int blue3 = c3.getBlue();
    int blue4 = c4.getBlue();

    int mixedRed = (red1 + red2 + red3 + red4) / 4;
    int mixedGreen = (green1 + green2 + green3 + green4) / 4;
    int mixedBlue = (blue1 + blue2 + blue3 + blue4) / 4;

    c = new Color(mixedRed, mixedGreen, mixedBlue);

    setBackground(c);
  }
}
```

And here are the errors I get:

```
Exception in thread "AWT-EventQueue-0" java.lang.IllegalMonitorStateException
    at java.base/java.lang.Object.wait(Native Method)
    at java.base/java.lang.Object.wait(Object.java:326)
    at ThreadPanel$1.mouseClicked(ThreadPanel.java:31)
    at java.desktop/java.awt.Component.processMouseEvent(Component.java:6639)
    at java.desktop/javax.swing.JComponent.processMouseEvent(JComponent.java:3342)
    at java.desktop/java.awt.Component.processEvent(Component.java:6401)
    at java.desktop/java.awt.Container.processEvent(Container.java:2263)
    at java.desktop/java.awt.Component.dispatchEventImpl(Component.java:5012)
    at java.desktop/java.awt.Container.dispatchEventImpl(Container.java:2321)
    at java.desktop/java.awt.Component.dispatchEvent(Component.java:4844)
    at java.desktop/java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.retargetMouseEvent(Container.java:4918)
    at java.desktop/java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.processMouseEvent(Container.java:4556)
    at java.desktop/java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.dispatchEvent(Container.java:4488)
    at java.desktop/java.awt.Container.dispatchEventImpl(Container.java:2307)
    at java.desktop/java.awt.Window.dispatchEventImpl(Window.java:2762)
    at java.desktop/java.awt.Component.dispatchEvent(Component.java:4844)
    at java.desktop/java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEventImpl(EventQueue.java:772)
    at java.desktop/java.awt.EventQueue$4.run(EventQueue.java:721)
    at java.desktop/java.awt.EventQueue$4.run(EventQueue.java:715)
    at java.base/java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(AccessController.java:391)
    at java.base/java.security.ProtectionDomain$JavaSecurityAccessImpl.doIntersectionPrivilege(ProtectionDomain.java:85)
    at java.base/java.security.ProtectionDomain$JavaSecurityAccessImpl.doIntersectionPrivilege(ProtectionDomain.java:95)
    at java.desktop/java.awt.EventQueue$5.run(EventQueue.java:745)
    at java.desktop/java.awt.EventQueue$5.run(EventQueue.java:743)
    at java.base/java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(AccessController.java:391)
    at java.base/java.security.ProtectionDomain$JavaSecurityAccessImpl.doIntersectionPrivilege(ProtectionDomain.java:85)
    at java.desktop/java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEvent(EventQueue.java:742)
    at java.desktop/java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpOneEventForFilters(EventDispatchThread.java:203)
    at java.desktop/java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForFilter(EventDispatchThread.java:124)
    at java.desktop/java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForHierarchy(EventDispatchThread.java:113)
    at java.desktop/java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(EventDispatchThread.java:109)
    at java.desktop/java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(EventDispatchThread.java:101)
    at java.desktop/java.awt.EventDispatchThread.run(EventDispatchThread.java:90)
```

Comment: Why are you calling `wait()` in the `MouseListener` ? That will almost certainly make everything hang.

Comment: This is exactly what is happening. But the thread must stop when you click on its panel and I don't know how to do it any other way than through ```MouseListener```.

Comment: You seem to be confusing the thread that runs your Runnable, which you are starting yourself in your `main` method, and the thread that runs your MouseAdapter, which is the Swing Event Dispatch Thread. If you make that one wait, you're basically freezing all other events, including background color changes. Why don't you just check the `active` flag in your `run` loop ?

Comment: Thank you! I don't know why I didn't think of that. Now stopping and resuming the background works as intended. But I still don't know how can I stop using the color of stopped thread in calculating the average. Is there any way I can get to the isActive flag of another thread/panel, specifically, adjacent panels?

Comment: I guess you could just add attributes to the ThreadPanel class, holding references to the neighbours ? Remember to synchronize all access to the `isActive` variable.